# Global scope for actions for scala-oauth2-provider with play2 scala

Tags: scala, playframework, scope, oauth-2.0

I have trouble dealing with scope (access level, OAuth2) and Scala.
I would like to have these use cases :

- define a global scope for the controller. Being able to override this global parameter for some actions.
- don't define a global parameter, but specify for each action the scope

This code is an example of what I want :

```
package controllers

import scalaoauth2.provider.OAuth2Provider

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class MyController extends GlobalAuthController

  // define global scope
  implicit val scope = Scope.User

  // By default, if no parameter, the scope is the implicit value previously defined
  def user = ActionWithAuth { request =>
    Ok("hello user or admin")
  }

  def admin = ActionWithAuth(Scope.Admin) {
    Ok("hello admin")
  }
}
```

I use `nulab/scala-oauth2-provider` library. According to the doc, I have created this :

```
trait OAuth2ActionComposition {
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext

  def ActionWithAuth[U](implicit scope: Scope): ActionBuilder[({type λ[A] = AuthInfoRequest[A, User]})#λ] = {
    Logger.info("Scope : " + scope.toString)
    AuthorizedActionFunction(new Users(scope)) compose Action
  }
}

object OAuth2ActionComposition extends OAuth2ActionComposition {
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.defaultContext
}
```

But with that code I get a Compilation error : missing parameter type at line `def user = ActionWithAuth { request =>` [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1y1q.png)

It works when I explicitly pass the implicit parameter (e.g `def user = ActionWithAuth(scope) { request =>`). WTF ! But it's not handy.

I cannot figure out why this error appears. I've tried some other ways but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" it thanks to [Silhouette](http://silhouette.mohiva.com/) built-in `com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Authorization`. 
See http://silhouette.mohiva.com/docs/authorization.

Indeed, thanks to Silhouette, it's possible to define an Authorization. E.g. :

```
case class WithProvider(provider: String) extends Authorization[User, CookieAuthenticator] {
  def isAuthorized[B](user: User, authenticator: CookieAuthenticator)(
    implicit request: Request[B], messages: Messages) = {

    Future.successful(user.loginInfo.providerID == provider)
  }
}
```

Then, to use this "filter :

```
def myAction = SecuredAction(WithProvider("twitter")) { implicit request =>
  // do something here
}
```

These filters can be combined easely.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Have a look at this article: [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will try to update my answer to match required content. In fact, my answer is not the direct answer to the question I asked. It's more a workaround. This is why I answered like this.